# Possible to shut down a Flask app without starting/stopping a server, calling os.kill, or using command line?

Tags: python, flask

I need to start and stop a simple Python app on a Flask server after the app runs and modifies files in the home directory. The app is housed on G Cloud. I've researched similar questions that involve using the command line, os, and http.server to stop the app. None of these approaches will work in my case. The best option seems to be to make a request to an app route that contains a request.environment.get function, which I've tried to do here. But the script triggers the following tracebacks: `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a Response.` And `TypeError: shutdown_server() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`. Can I shut down the app using a script and without starting/stopping a server (i.e., using http.server)? If so, what am I doing wrong?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import textwrap
from hidden import consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
import tweepy
from tweepy import TweepError
import requests

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = 'templates')
app.config.update(
   SERVER_NAME = "127.0.0.1:8080"
)

@app.route('/')

def check_status():
   with open('app_status.txt') as f:
       status = f.read()
   status = status.rstrip()
   status = int(status)
   if status == 1:
       with open('app_status.txt', 'w+') as f:
           f.write(F'0')
       print('exiting')    
       return requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/shutdown')
   if status == 0:
       return get_chunk()

def get_chunk():

   ...

   # Create the app's weboutput by rendering an html template

   if tweet:
       with open('app_status.txt', 'w+') as f:
           f.write(F'1')
       with app.app_context():
           return render_template('index.html', excrpt = chunk_wrp), requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/shutdown')
           
         
@app.route("/shutdown", methods=['GET'])

def shutdown():
   shutdown_func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
   if shutdown_func is None:
       raise RuntimeError('Not running werkzeug')
   shutdown_func()
   return "Shutting down..."

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Why do you expect `stop` to get called? And how does `app_status.py` integrate into this? What issue are you _actually_ trying to solve? This seems like a very convoluted way to achieve something that could be solved in a far more straight forward way.

Comment: Thanks, MatsLindh. I removed the stop() call, so hopefully that problem has been solved. App_status.py is being used to establish a condition for shutting down. Yes, this is undoubtedly more convoluted than necessary. Perhaps a global variable could be used instead. But I'm more concerned about the shutdown issue.

Comment: Your explanation says that you need to shut down to restart the process; why do you need to restart the process? That will inform how this should be done, and what tools to use. There usually isn't a good reason for actually terminating the process from inside Flask, but instead ask the wsgi server (for example gunicorn) to handle restarts if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, MatsLindh. My plan is to have the service run once daily using a cron job, after importing new data from an updated file in the home directory. Each instance updates the file. This is the reason for some of the complications. Also, I want to avoid the service running all the time for no reason.

Comment: Sounds like Flask is a bad fit for what you want to do. What's the reasoning for using Flask at all, and not just running a python script through cron as necessary?

Comment: The reason for Flask is that it's used for development in the G Cloud. When deployed the service will run on gunicorn. I would use a script and cron locally (if that's what you mean) except the app is designed to run daily for a long time and don't want it to be dependent on my local system being available.

Answer (score 0):

A look at the mod_wsgi documentation yielded code for killing a daemon process. For the moment, this appears to be working:

```
import signal
import os
#...#
def shutdown():
    return os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
```